# How do I maximize a vector

Tags: r, vector, max

I'd like to maximize numbers in a vector and get the results as a new vector

Like this:

```
w <- 0:10
maximizer <- function(w){
  max(10, w + 5)
}
```

I'm expecting getting a vector (10,10,10,10,10,10,11,12,13,14,15), but all I'm getting is 15. I know weird ways of fixing this, but I'm sure there must be an easier way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `max` you should use `pmax`:

```
maximizer <- function(w) pmax(10, w + 5)
maximizer(0:10)
# [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

since

> `pmax()` and `pmin()` take one or more vectors as arguments, recycle
>   them to common length and return a single vector giving the ‘*parallel*’ maxima (or minima) of the argument vectors.

while

> `max` and `min` return the maximum or minimum of all the values present in their arguments

Answer (score 0):

you could use a `for-loop` with an `ifelse` statement albeit not as elegant as the solution posted:

```
for(i in seq_along(w)){
  w[[i]] <- ifelse(w[[i]]+5 < 10, 10, w[[i]] + 5)
}


[1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: `ifelse()` is vectorized, so it could be just `ifelse(w + 5 <= 10, 10, w + 5)`

Comment: @Rich Scriven - for me that kicks an error `Error in w[[i]] <- ifelse(w + 5 < 10, 10, w + 5) : 
  more elements supplied than there are to replace`

Comment: With the `for` loop, you may as well just use `if` and `else`: `w[[i]] <- if(w[[i]]+5 < 10) 10 else w[[i]] + 5`

Comment: Imo- curious to know if there’s  an advantage to using your approach?